# Is there a way to calculate what the products of uranium-236 fission will be?

Tags: nuclear-physics

Such as an equation that uses temperature and thermal neutron velocity to find the mass of the individual products, or the probability that the products have x number of protons and y number of neutrons?

Comment: Read the [Yield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission_product) section in this wiki page, including the image provided.

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there was anything more specific than "more likely that the two fission products have similar mass"